# String Comparison with Array Item and String with VBA in Excel

Tags: vba, excel

This is probably a simple one, but I can't seem to find out what's wrong:

```
if temp_array(1) = temp_string2 & temp_array(2) = "w" then
....
end if
```

the values are:

temp_array(1) = "test1"

temp_string2 = "test2"

temp_array(2) = "w"

I get a type mismatch error highlighting the conditional comparisons...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`&` is string concatenation, not logical `and`.

```
if temp_array(1) = temp_string2 And temp_array(2) = "w" then
```